# VBA copy active cell data to all active sheet error

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 sheets and 1 master sheets.
I want to copy cell data in master to rest of the sheets.
It always thrw "Runtime error 1004. can anyone help?

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
 `Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    Dim columnName As String
    columnName = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)
    Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range(columnName & ActiveCell.Row), xlFillWithAll
End Sub` 
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In particular, why do you use `ActiveCell` instead of Target? and why do you want to copy from the master sheet instead of the sheet being edited? Besides of that, do you have protected worksheets in the workbook?

Comment: Why in this way?

`Dim ws As Worksheet, rngTemp As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start")
Set rngTemp = ActiveCell
Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.rngTemp, xlFillWithAll`

The other Sheets arn't protected?

Comment: other sheets are not protect. i am new to vba .i google some where and edit the codes and change a little.

Answer (score 1):

All sheets should be assigned to array and the range to fill must be from a sheet within the array. Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shtArray As Variant
    shtArray = Array("Master", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    Sheets(shtArray).FillAcrossSheets Target

    'Dim columnName As String
    'columnName = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)
    'Sheets(shtArray).FillAcrossSheets ws.Range(columnName & ActiveCell.Row), xlFillWithAll
End Sub
```

Comment: can we not have array as there maybe new sheets added.

Comment: @MVCnewbie - For using `FillAcrossSheets ` array is needed. Another option would be loop through all the sheets then.

Comment: @MVCnewbie - You can also save the list of sheets in any of the worksheet and use in code as array.